# Get headers on Appengine GAE PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I found out that the common PHP function `getallheaders()` is unavailable on GAE. How do i access custom headers set by the client? For example an AJAX post contains a header `"RestAuth: pk_1234123"`.

Answer (score 2):

`getallheaders()` is an [apache extension](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php).

You can retrieve the headers from the `$_SERVER` superglobal. All of the request headers are capitalized and the header name is prepended with 'HTTP_'.

In you're case, the header 'RestAuth' would be available as `$_SERVER['HTTP_RESTAUTH']`.

Comment: There is a useful function on the php man page for use where getallheaders() is not available - http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php

Answer (score 1):

To follow up @Stuart..straight from the man page referenced by @Tom

```
if (!function_exists('getallheaders')) 
{ 
    function getallheaders() 
    { 
           $headers = ''; 
       foreach ($_SERVER as $name => $value) 
       { 
           if (substr($name, 0, 5) == 'HTTP_') 
           { 
               $headers[str_replace(' ', '-', ucwords(strtolower(str_replace('_', ' ', substr($name, 5)))))] = $value; 
           } 
       } 
       return $headers; 
    } 
}
```

So basically from your client you post `RestAuth` which turns into `HTTP_RESTAUTH` on the server which above function will finally return as `Restauth`. Play with the ucwords() if you prefer differently.